# Toogle between upperCase and LowerCase Switch on a submitted form

Tags: reactjs, state, strapi, uppercase

I am making a website where customers can submit a form with their personal data, like address, phone and email. The form sends the submitted data to an "Answers page" where the company can copy the details into their internal system. The answers page is made as a form which is *read only*.
The data is sent through an strapi API, then fetched again to the answers page. Everything is working fine.

The problem is that I want a simple Toogle between uppercase and lowercase letters for the submitted answers on the answers page. For some reason I cant get it to work. I have tried with useState and LocalStorage. I can console that the actuall boolean changes between true/false, but the text dosent rerender to uppercase and lowercase. I am using a MUI switch to toogle between uppercase and lowercase.

//Settings Context

```
export const SettingsContext = createContext();

export const SettingsProvider = props => {
  const [upperCase, setUpperCase] = useState(localStorage.getItem("upperCase"));
  document.documentElement.setAttribute("upperCase", upperCase);

  return (
    <SettingsContext.Provider value={[ upperCase, setUpperCase ]}>
      { props.children }
    </SettingsContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

//AnswerPage

```
 const [upperCase, setUpperCase] = useContext(SettingsContext);

  return (
    <>
      {answers
        .sort((b, a) => a.id - b.id)
        .filter((item, idx) => idx < 1)
        .map((item) => {
          const { country, street, postal, city, phone, email, publishedAt } =
            item.attributes;
          const phoneFormated = phone ? phone.replace(/\s+/g, "") : "";
          let countryFormated;
          if(upperCase === true) {
            countryFormated = country.toUpperCase();
          } else {
            countryFormated = country.toLowerCase();
          }

  <FormTextField
                    onClick={copyCountry}
                    InputProps={{
                      readOnly: true,
                      endAdornment: (
                        <InputAdornment position="end">
                          <IconButton
                            edge="end"
                            color="primary"
                            sx={{ boxShadow: "none" }}
                            onClick={copyCountry}
                          >
                            <ContentCopyIcon
                              sx={{ height: ".8em", width: ".8em" }}
                            />
                          </IconButton>
                        </InputAdornment>
                      ),
                    }}
                    variant="standard"
                    label="Country"
                    type="text"
                    defaultValue={country ? countryFormated : ""}
                    inputRef={countryRef}
                  />
```

//switch

```
function AnswersSettingsModal({ open, handleClose }) {
  const [upperCase, setUpperCase] = useContext(SettingsContext);

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setUpperCase(event.target.checked);
    localStorage.setItem("upperCase", event.target.checked);
    document.documentElement.setAttribute("upperCase", event.target.checked);
  };

  return (
    <ModalLayout open={open} handleClose={handleClose}>
      <Typography id="transition-modal-title" variant="h6" component="h2">
        Show big or small letters
      </Typography>
      <FormGroup>
        <Stack direction="row" spacing={1} alignItems="center">
          <FormControlLabel
            sx={{ marginLeft: "0" }}
            control={
              <>
                <Typography>Small letters</Typography>
                <Switch
                  checked={upperCase}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  name="upperCase"
                />
                <Typography>Big letters</Typography>
              </>
            }
          />
        </Stack>
      </FormGroup>
      <button className="btn-close" onClick={handleClose}>
        Close
      </button>
    </ModalLayout>
  );
}

export default AnswersSettingsModal;
```

Comment: why not just `defaultValue={countryFormated}` or `value={countryFormated}`?

Comment: Found the solution. using value instead of defaultValue. Probably the DefaultValue is not supposed to change. Thanks!